# Select two last inserted rows from mysql based on a field

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

`SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2 FROM table1 WHERE something = 'x' ORDER BY time_of_insertion DESC LIMIT 2`

What I want is to get the last two inserted rows of the table, **one with a certain field1 ('1' for example) and another with another field1 ('2' for example)**. So, it's not really the last two rows, what I want is the last one from one certain field1 and the last one from a different field1. When I tried the query, `DISTINCT` was not respected. Any ideas on why and on **how to solve this**?

Comment: How are field1 and field2 defined? Is there any way to say this field has been updated/inserted last? Based on your current query my guess of your table layout is saying: No possible. Remember, SQL or storing data inside a MySQL table is not really sequential. It's just storing data where it fits and so an order is done by random

Comment: @frian table structure is irrelevant. If you want to contribute please do so, else don't just downvote if you can't workaround the problem. I asked for a specific solution and `Remember, SQL or storing data inside a MySQL table is not really sequential. It's just storing data where it fits and so an order is done by random` isn't even of interest since I didn't mention otherwise but explicitly defined an order and tryied to combo it with distinct, failing. That's the point of the question, if you're still interested.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question ... But ... having field1 and field2 inserted at the same time, time_of_insertion most likely will be the same on the same row. So your query is returning what you are asking for. Last values for field1 and field2. If this is not, maybe an example could help a little to light up the party.

Answer (score 1):

I think a `UNION` will do what you want.  Select a single row with your exact criteria, and then combine its resultset with that of another `SELECT` statement that selected the other row you wanted.

It's hard to be concrete and definitive when your example is rather generalized, but something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1 WHERE something = 'x' ORDER BY time_of_insertion DESC LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1 WHERE something = 'y' ORDER BY time_of_insertion DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Notice it's one statement: only the second `SELECT` has a semi-colon terminating it.